# ModuleNotFound error in Python when trying to import nested modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I am working on a Python project with the basic folder structure listed below, and examples of what each Python file contains is in curly brackets.

```
|   generate_recommendations.py
├───.ipynb_checkpoints
├───.vscode
├───csv
├───dao
|   |   ratingDAO.py { contains a class named RatingDAO }
│   ├───config
│   ├───core
|   |       rating.py { contains a class named Rating }
│   ├───db
```

**OBJECTIVE**: I want to import rating.py in ratingDAO.py, and in turn want to import ratingDAO.py into generate_recommendations.py, and have all imports working.

I have added the following import statement in the file ratingDAO.py

```
from core.rating import Rating
```

And I have also added the following import statement in the file generate_recommendations.py

```
from dao.ratingDAO import RatingDAO
```

When I execute ratingDAO.py, it runs without any error.

But when I try to execute generate_recommendations.py, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_recommendations.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dao.ratingDAO import RatingDAO
  File "D:\MEGASync\BSc Computer\Research Papers\recommendation-engine\dao\ratingDAO.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core.rating import Rating
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

I am unable to resolve the error. I have seen approx ten posts on StackOverflow related to nested imports but I was unable to find examples where the author tried to import two levels deep.

If such imports are not possible in Python, I am open to ideas on how I should go about managing the files in my Python project.

In Java, I would've used the following folder structure,

```
├───recommendation
|   |   GenerateRecommendations.java
│   ├───core
|   |     Rating.java
│   └───dao
|         RatingDAO.java
```

and used the following code to import Rating.java in RatingDAO.java,

```
import recommendation.core.Rating;
```

and used the following to code to import RatingDAO.java into GenerateRecommendations.java

```
import dao.RatingDAO;
```

and everything would have worked, but the same wasn't working for Python which is why I chose the initial specified folder structure.

P.S This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. I tried my best to describe my issue by referring to other posts. Apologies in advance if it does not match the standards of good questions.

Hoping for a reply! :-)

Comment: don't take this badly, but Python does not have the 1 class per file Java limitation.  Don't write Java in Python.  https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html  I realize that this does not answer your question, but your module structure seems unnecessarily complex to me.  `ratingDAO.py { contains a class named RatingDAO }` => I was already thinking *hah! a Java programmer* before you mentioned the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `python generate_recommendations.py` this puts the script's directory on the path (`sys.path` which is searched for modules when importing). When you use `from core.rating import Rating` in `ratingDAO.py` then it will search the path for a package called `core` but since the `dao` directory is not on the path it cannot be found.

A solution is to use a relative import in the `ratingDAO.py` module:

```
from .core.rating import Rating
```

This way it will search relative to its own location for the `core` package. If you want to run `ratingDAO.py` from the top-level directory you can do so via `python -m dao.ratingDAO` (this put's the current working directory on the path and then searches `sys.path` for a module called `dao.ratingDAO` and executes it).

Or you can use an absolute import relative to the top-level directory of the hierarchy:

```
from dao.core.rating import Rating
```

Comment: Following your suggestion, I used the following import statement in `ratingDAO.py` module, `from .core.rating import Rating`. Now, if I run `generate_recommendations.py` I do not get any `ModuleNotFoundError`. Thank you. But, if I now try to run `ratingDAO.py` seperately using `python ratingDAO.py`, it gives me the following error. `from .core.rating import Rating ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.core'; '__main__' is not a package`. In a similar manner, if I use `from dao.core.rating import Rating` in `ratingDAO.py` and run `generate_recommendations.py` I get no error.

Comment: But, upon executing `ratingDAO.py` as stated above, I get `from dao.core.rating import Rating ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dao'`

Comment: @RanajoySaha You need to run `python -m dao.ratingDAO` from *outside* the `dao` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the code works. Thank you! Much appreciated!