# ModuleNotFoundError in Colaboratory

Tags: python, module, google-colaboratory, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run my project using the gpus but I can't get it to work.
I have ran the following commands:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

%cd gdrive/MyDrive/project_folder

import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/project_folder')
```

I then try to run my main script from project_folder by using

```
! python property_prediction/predict.py
```

In the first line of predict.py I import a module from the folder 'project_folder' but that gives this error in colab:

```
File "property_prediction/predict.py", line 17, in <module>
from GP.kernels import Shortest_Path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GP
```

Why is it not finding the folder GP which contains my kernels script?

Comment: Are you running this in the directory where python can see `GP`

Comment: Yes GP is in project_folder and that is the directory I am in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your running command with:

```
!python -m property_prediction.predict
```

Or better:

```
from property_prediction.predict import predict # or whatever your main function is called

predict()
```

**NB: This is of course assuming that you have a module named GP in the folder `project_folder`**

If none of this work, you might be interested in reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838741/modulenotfound-error-in-python-when-trying-to-import-nested-modules) or other articles about imports with python (this is most likely not a problem of google collab)